# What is the simplest approach to symbolizing points from a PostGIS-sourced layer by age?

Tags: qgis, postgis, symbology

I have a view in PostGIS that has a bunch of points and I want to symbolize in QGIS (3.2.2) by the age of the points. I am trying to use this expression (or something like it):
`day(age(ts, now()))`

But that doesn't appear to do anything (returns null).  The column is a timestamp (UTC).   Is there anything I need to do the **ts** timestamp value before passing into the age(,) function.

I know I could force it from the PostgreSql by adding a derived column in the view, but I feel like I wouldn't need to do that.

Comment: Could you add to your PostGIS View a ROW_NUMBER column that sorts the data by the method you've outlined, which then you could then use in QGIS to render / sort by?

Comment: so...I exited out QGIS. I opened it again and now the expression works.  weird.

Comment: Oh - that's good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In QGIS try using a conversion function on your timestamp field and the Now() Function:**

```
age(to_date(ts),to_date(now()))
```

This will allow you to calculate whole days rather than fractions of days.

*If you go the derived field route:*

**The following block of SQL Code should do the trick:**

```
SELECT date(now()) - date(ts)) AS age FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 2):

My original expression (and approach) was correct. Once I exited the QGIS application and re-opened, everything worked correctly.  And I am unable to reproduce that original behavior that prompted me to ask the question in the first place.

2 workarounds were suggested and both would work. [@Rob](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/128480/rob)'s answer produces a better explain plan when using a predicate with the view. [@DPSSpatial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9880/dpsspatial)'s  `row_number()` executes a bit slower--unless you need the view ordered by the timestamp every time, I would opt for the former.

Comment: That is strange that it wasn't working at first. Were you attempting to use a Categorized symbology or some other type? I tried using graduated and it was returning NULL and nothing would happen when I attempted to classify the data.

I attempted to edit my original answer with additional information on how you could use a conversion function in a QGIS expression to alter the timestamp field to a date field in order to get rounded off days instead of decimal days.

Comment: **Update:** I attempted to use the Graduated Symbology method and by explicitly using the expression `day(age(now(),ts))` I was able to get the results I was looking for. I also wanted to add further confirmation that using the conversion function _to_date()_ in this exercise yielded whole days instead of decimal days.